# Operator += class overloading : parameter error

Tags: class, operator-overloading, overloading

```
CPP-file:

Matrix2x2& operator +=(const Matrix2x2 & rhs)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for (int n = 0; n < 2; n++)
        {
            this->anArray.[i][n] += rhs.anArray[i][n];
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Header-file:

```
class Matrix2x2
{
private:
    double anArray[2][2];
public:
    Matrix2x2();
    Matrix2x2(int a, int b, int c, int d);
    void setArrayValues(int row, int column, double value);
    const double getArrayValues(int row, int column) const;
    Matrix2x2& operator +=(const Matrix2x2 & rhs)
};
```

Main file:

```
Matrix2x2 aMatrix(4,4,4,4);
Matrix2x2 bMatrix;
aMatrix += bMatrix;
```

When I try to run this, I get this:

error: 'Matrix2x2& operator+=(const Matrix2x2&)' must take exactly two arguments

I can't see why?

I replaced it with

```
Matrix2x2& Matrix2x2::operator+=(const Matrix2x2 & rhs);
```

and then I got these errors:

```
error: extra qualification 'Matrix2x2::' on member 'operator+='
```

in the header file and

```
error: expected unqualified-id before '[' token|
```

in this line:

```
 this->anArray.[i][n] += rhs.anArray[i][n];
```

UPDATE2

I've shown you my class declaration in the header file, the invocation in the main file and the function definition in my cpp file. What else is there to show? I've currently corrected all that you pointed out, but I still get one of the same errors:

```
error: extra qualification 'Matrix2x2::' on member 'operator+=
```

in the cpp and header file.

Comment: show how do you invoke `+=` for your objects, please.

Comment: Isn't that supposed to be `Matrix2x2& Matrix2x2::operator+=` ...

Comment: In my class it's defined :
    Matrix2x2& operator +=(const Matrix2x2 & rhs);
I haven't tried to invoke the += operator, I've just written the functions as of yet. Could that have anything to do with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, a large number of issues.

First, in your header file, this line needs to be *within a the class declaration* of `Matrix2x2` (preferably under a `public:` label)

```
Matrix2x2& operator +=(const Matrix2x2 & rhs);
```

Second, you need to put your definition *in the CPP file* and it needs to look something like this:

```
Matrix2x2& Matrix2x2::operator+=(const Matrix2x2 & rhs)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for (int n = 0; n < 2; n++)
        {
            this->anArray[i][n] += rhs.anArray[i][n];
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Third, you have an extra "`.`" within your for loop. Change it from:

```
this->anArray.[i][n] += rhs.anArray[i][n];
```

to:

```
this->anArray[i][n] += rhs.anArray[i][n];
```

I can't guarantee that there aren't more issues. But those are the ones that I see based on what you've shown us.

Comment: If I try to replace it with
 
Matrix2x2& Matrix2x2::operator+=

I get the following: error: 

    extra qualification 'Matrix2x2::' on member 'operator+='

and also:

expected unqualified-id before '[' token in this line:

    this->anArray.[i][n] += rhs.anArray[i][n];

Comment: @user1784297, then in that case, as many people have said, ***we need to see more code***. Don't reply back unless you first acknowledge that request.

Comment: can you explain please, what does `this->anArray.[i][n]` mean? (I am about the DOT there).

Comment: I'm referencing the calling object with "this" and using -> as a pointer to the member array "anArray".

Comment: @user1784297, the syntax `anArray.[i][n]` is an error. Change it as I showed you